# Laravel & Vue JS Updating prop value after AXIOS

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to vue js and I've been cracking at this issue for a whole day with no luck.

I've added notifications via pusher on laravel and currently am using Vue JS to display the unread notifications, which works as intended. The only issue I'm having is that once the notification bell icon is clicked, I want to **update the notification count to be zero**, currently that is **only possible upon page refresh**.

Here my my vue JS Code

```
    <template>
   <li class="nav-item dropdown" @click="markNotificationAsRead">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
         <div class = "icon icon-shape bg-gradient-red text-white rounded-circle shadow icon-notification">{{unreadNotifications.length}}</div>
         <i class="ni ni-bell-55"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-xl  dropdown-menu-right  py-0 overflow-hidden">
         <!-- Dropdown header -->
         <div class="px-3 py-3">
            <h6 class="text-sm text-muted m-0">You have <strong class="text-primary">13</strong> notifications.</h6>
         </div>
         <notification-item v-for="unread in unreadNotifications" :key ="unread.data.id" :unread="unread"></notification-item>
         <!-- View all -->
         <a href="#!" class="dropdown-item text-center text-primary font-weight-bold py-3">View all</a>
      </div>
   </li>
</template>
<script>
   import NotificationItem from './NotificationItem.vue';
   import Vue from 'vue';
   export default {
       props:['unreads', 'userid'],
       components:{NotificationItem},
       data() {
           return {
           unreadNotifications: this.unreads
       }
   },
   methods: {
   props:['unreads', 'userid'],
       markNotificationAsRead() {
           if(this.unreadNotifications.length){
       axios.get('markAsRead')
           .then((response) => {
          
//This is where I want to add the rule to rerender the vue element to display notification count as 0

           });
           }
       }
   },
       mounted() {
           console.log('Component mounted.');
           Echo.private('App.Models.User.' + this.userid)
               .notification((notification) => {
               console.log(notification);
   
               let newUnreadNotifications={data:{thread:notification.thread, user:notification.user}};
               this.unreadNotifications.push(newUnreadNotifications);
       });
   }
   }
</script>
```

I'm hoping someone could give me some insight as to what I'm doing wrong here. I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: set `unreadNotifications` to empty array

Comment: Hi, Nilesh, that didn't work either.

Comment: setting this `this.unreadNotifications=[]` still shows unread notifications??

Comment: Oh I think you've misunderstood my question, what I'm trying to solve is, upon clicking the bell icon and the axios method is called, I want {{unreadNotifications.length}} to display as 0 instead of the original count of unread notifications. The value only changes to 0 when page is reloaded, and yes setting to this.unreadNotifications=[] still displays unread notifications

Comment: i understood your question.. i can see you hard coded `13</strong> notifications` is it a typo?

Comment: That's just there for placeholder sake, the code i'm referring to is 3 lines above that :)

Comment: You don't have valid component JavaScript code there.

Comment: Valid code would look similar to [this](https://pastebin.com/MbL6xQS9).